Regulatory Authority for denied boarding compensation for return leg of USA to Canada roundtrip flight
A USA Citizen was involuntarily denied boarding by Air Canada for the YYZ-EWR leg of a EWR-YYZ-EWR round-trip.
In case regulatory authorities need to get involved to receive compensation, do I reach out to United States DOT or Canada CTA?

You citizenships is not relevant, but where did you buy the ticket? (which country?)

For completeness, what was the reason?

@GiacomoCatenazzi Ticket was purchased from a USA based web site (actually from united airlines that was selling a codeshared ticket on Air Canada metal)

It doesn't appear to be the America DOT
From: https://www.transportation.gov/individuals/aviation-consumer-protection/bumping-oversales

Bumped passengers are NOT eligible for compensation in the following situations:
Flights Departing a Foreign Location

You may have more luck with the Canadians: From https://rppa-appr.ca/eng/right/denied-boarding-bumping

Denied Boarding: A Guide explains what denied boarding is, and what passenger rights and airline obligations apply in the event a passenger is denied boarding. These apply to flights to, from and within Canada, including connecting flights.

